# how to correct AttributeError

Tags: python, attributes, ncurses, attributeerror, curses

i have imported ncurses but it shows me this error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jai.best-PC\Desktop\the real snk game.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ncurses
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ncurses.py", line 8, in <module>
    import _curses
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_curses\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    import has_key
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_curses\has_key.py", line 11, in <module>
    _curses.KEY_A1: 'ka1',
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'KEY_A1'
```

why i get an Attribute Error here while

```
 import _curses


_capability_names = {
    _curses.KEY_A1: 'ka1',
```

i have it here in has_key.py module

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you expecting KEY_A1 or ka1 to be?

Comment: im trying to use the keyboard characters like UP ARROW , DOWN ARROW etc..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on windows, python curses isn't provided inbuilt.
Try:

`pip install windows-curses`